# Where to find documentation for Selenium WebDriver in Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Could anyone point me to useful documentation sites for writing selenium webdriver scripts with Ruby language?

I am referring link 'http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs' but also need other site.

Comment: Try this link: http://anahorny.blogspot.in/2011/08/selenium-webdriver-ruby-tutorial.html. Its good to begin with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend those looking to learn Ruby's Selenium WebDriver web bindings to search Google, look at the latest [updated docs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver.html).

Also, use solid tools like [Elemential Selenium](http://elemental-selenium.com/) to learn new tips and tricks, follow other users of SWD on Twitter, and most importantly, read other people's code. You can do this easily by searching on Github for "gem 'selenium-webdriver'". I learned some of the best ways to code and program in Ruby and Selenium WebDriver by reading the code for [Capybara](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara), [Watir-Webdriver](https://github.com/watir/watir-webdriver), [Page-Object](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object), etc.

Answer (score 2):

Here is best doc where you can find all classes and methods (see right top corner of the page):

http://rubydoc.info/gems/selenium-webdriver/2.2.0/

Comment: Why not refer to the latest updated docs? http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/rb/Selenium/WebDriver.html

Comment: Actually, the doc I gave is same as you gave. For reaching to doc you gave, you'll have to browse the link I gave.

Comment: Actually, no, your docs are referring to the out-of-date 2.2.0 version. The latest version is 2.33.0. The link I gave directs you to the latest docs.